# Which Java collection allows fastest element removal?

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for a collection that allows fastest element removal. I tested ArrayList on 1 million rows and it turns out removing the first element is faster than removing the last one. It takes about 50 seconds to remove one million elements

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestArray {

    final int numberOfElements = 1000000; 

    public void testArray () { 

    // test array 
    ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) { 
        testArray.add("" + Math.random()); 
    }

    // testing speed when removing the first element  
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    while (true) { 
        if (testArray.isEmpty()) { 
            System.out.println("Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the first element " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            break; 
        } 
        else { 
            String testString = testArray.get(0); 
            testArray.remove(testString); 
        }
    } 

    testArray = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) { 
        testArray.add("" + Math.random()); 
    } 
    // testing speed when removing the last   element  
        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        while (true) { 
            if (testArray.isEmpty()) { 
                System.out.println("Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the last element " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2));
                break; 
            } 
            else { 
                String testString = testArray.get(testArray.size()-1); 
                testArray.remove(testString); 
            }
        }



    } 

}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the fastest possible way. Is 50 seconds the fastest way? Or is there any better collection, for example will `LinkedList` do it faster? Or what is the fastest collection to remove elements one by one?

Comment: If you're removing by value (rather than by index), use a Set. Otherwise you're forcing it to iterate the entire collection to find your value.

Comment: Usually a data structure doesn't involve only deletions - you should consider the other operations (that you need) as well

Comment: Index will work for me too. I'm looking for the fastest way

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed, youre measuring side effects, not the actual code. Read on how to do correct microbenchmarks.

Comment: And that is proven by the fact that you got the fastest case exactly back to front. Removing the last element from an 'ArrayList` is *considerably* faster than removing the first.

Comment: @user207421 But finding it isn't.

Comment: @shmosel the index of the last element is always `size() - 1`, no need to loop is you always want the last element

Comment: @Ferrybig Who said we want the last element?

Comment: @Ferrybig but the `remove(Object)` method doesn’t know that the OP passes the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You should consider **LinkedList** which has **O(1)** Big O performance for **remove** operation **(Explanation below)**, while ArrayList is O(n).
2) You can try HashSet if you are not interested in duplicates.

LinkedList Remove:

1) LinkedList removal at the beginning and end is constant time since traversal is not required.

2) It takes longer time for removing the middle elements because the element needs to be found first.

3) If you have an iterator at the location you want to remove, then remove is constant time.

Comment: LinkedList removal is only O(1) at the start and end. Removal in the middle takes far longer.

Comment: @user2357112 Depends, if youre removing via a node handle, its still constant time (e.g. via the ListIterator)

Comment: @user2357112 If you're already traversing it to find a value, removal will be cheaper for LinkedList.

Comment: @Zabuza Or via `remove(Object)`, as in the question.

Comment: @shmosel: `remove(Object)` is not constant time. Removal through an iterator already positioned at the element you want to remove is constant time, but that depends on a specific usage pattern that the answer makes no mention of.

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't say it's constant time. I'm saying the linear part of that method, namely the iteration, is required whether it's ArrayList or LinkedList, but the subsequent removal will be in constant time for LinkedList only.

Comment: `ArrayDeque` also supports fast removal at the beginning and end, without the overhead of `LinkedList`. And when removal via index is ok, `ArrayList` may still be the preferred choice.

Answer (score 2):

The best collection for performance is TreeSet because if you insert objects in according to Comparable / Comparator, collection will be orded.

My times:
ArrayList
Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the first element 698
Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the last element 121960

TreeSet:
Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the first element 55
Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the last element 50

**WARNING:** With this solutions you can't have duplicate objects in the collection.

```
@Test
    public void testTreeSet() {
        /* RESULTS
         * Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the first element 55
         * Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the last element 50
         */

        // test array
        TreeSet<String> testArray = new TreeSet<String>();
        int numberOfElements = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
            testArray.add("" + Math.random());
        }

        // testing speed when removing the first element
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            if (testArray.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the first element "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
                break;
            } else {
                //String testString = testArray.get(0);
                String testString = testArray.first();
                testArray.remove(testString);
            }
        }

        testArray = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
            testArray.add("" + Math.random());
        }
        // testing speed when removing the last element
        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true) {
            if (testArray.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Milliseconds to fisnish when removing the last element "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime2));
                break;
            } else {
                //String testString = testArray.get(testArray.size() - 1);
                String testString = testArray.last();
                testArray.remove(testString);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First: There must be something wrong with your benchmark, a **ArrayList** removes elements much slower then adding some. This is because the array must not have gaps in the underlaying array. So elements need to be shifted if you remove everywhere but in the end.

This answer depends wether you want to remove index-based or value-based.
In general, index-based operations are faster because no expansive value comparisons need to be made.
Since if you want to remove elements you must have added them once, it is helpful to consider the add complexity as well

- **ArrayList:** Add: O(n), amortized O(1) (in practice cheap). Remove is always O(n), Find O(1) if index-based, O(n) if value based

Example in practice for the effect of amortized analysis: Adding one million elements in a row will result in 10 million copies. However the number of copies is O(log n), n is the number of consecutive add operations.

- **LinkedList** Add: O(n) at average, AddFirst/Last O(1), removeLast/First O(1), find O(n), getFirstElement/GetLastElement O(1). Note here: You have to know, that the element you search for is in the end/beginning and call the corresponding method.

So far, if you have a lot of consecutive add/remove operations and few search operations (except getting the first or last element), I recommend you to use **LinkedList**.

If you have no two identical objects, that is ( `Object.equals(sameObject)` ) returns `true` for exactly the *same* object. you should use **LinkedHashSet** It has O(1) for all operations, but equal objects can only be contained once.
Unfortunately index-based search is here not possible, the methods are also not snychronized. But there is always a trade-off.

Some theory: According to the papers mentioned [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/data-structure-with-search-insert-and-delete-in-amortised-time-o1) we cannot do better then amortized Omega(log n) for arbitraty adding and removal of elements.

Comment: ArrayList is a dynamic array.

Comment: The wiki page mentions nothing about null values. Allowing gaps in the underlying array would make indexed lookups O(n).

Comment: @shmosel You are right. I knew that we can bypass the nasty shifts when we use a additional balanced tree structure, so I thought in this special case there was a good chance to obtain **O(1)** . Apparently not, I will update my answer.

Comment: You “example in practice” makes no sense. Where does this “10 million copies” come from and what do you mean with “number of copies” that you claim to be “O(log n)” despite “O(…)” is not a number at all?